# jQuery - change background image on mouseover but not if element is selected?

Tags: jquery

I need set a background image on mouseover, but not if the element is selected.

Im using the jscrollpane:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

I need I need the scrollbar (div.jspDrag) to have a different background image when a users hovers their mouse over it. However I need the background image to change back to its original when the drag the scrollbar.

The hover pseudo-class is standard, but how do i recognize if the element is being dragged? Should I have a jquery listener to see if the mouse button is being held down?

Thanks

EDIT
Ive tried the following but it does nothing:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".node-type-collection-public .jspDrag").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look on this: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ jQuery knows a lot of events, so you can distinguish easily if the user is hovering the scrollbar or is clicking on it.

Comment: Ive updated by question with the code ive tried but nothing happens. Is their a syntax error there somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-edited after your edit -

```
$(".node-type-collection-public .jspDrag").bind('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});

$(".node-type-collection-public .jspDrag").bind('click',function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
});
```

When you mouseover, it'll change to red. If you click (and drag) it will change back to in this case blue.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I ran ahead without looking at the page code properly. Jscrollpane adds the following css when you hover or drag the bar: .jspHover .jspActive. So I can do this with just CSS.

Thanks for your code. Ill see if my client is happy with the CSS solution. They may want fade in and delays, etc, which will mean doing it in js after all.

Thanks